# Program to get a Context Free Grammar from a Pushdown Automata?

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata, pushdown-automaton

I need some help to figure out what is the grammar that describes the following language. In fact, I also need help to formalize the language.

First, lets define positive gradient as 2 symboos where the second is bigger than the first.

So 01 is a positive gradient, 12 too, etc..

Negative gradient are 2 symbols where the second is smaller than the first.

The language is defined as it follows:

The alphabet is: 0, 1, 2

The words accepted by L are those that have the same number of positive and negative gradients. Some examples:

0 is an accepted word. 1 and 2 too, as they have no positive or negative gradients.

012 is not a word, as it has 2 positive gradients and 0 negative.

Some words from the language:
00000000022222222111111
02120
010101210

Ok,so the grammar will look something like:

S := 0 | 1 | 2 | ASB

For each positive gradient added (A) a negative must be added, so they are equal.

But i dont know how to do to add gradients in a way they remain equal. Any help?

In fact, we have a PDA recognizing the language. So we could use the method described at the textbook (M. Sipser bestseller) to transform PDA into CFG, but it s quite difficult for me to figure out 27^4 possibilities, but not for a program of course.

Comment: Would it be something like 0 | 1 | 2 | ((01)(10))*|((12)(21))*|((02)(20))*|(00)*|(11)*|(22)*? My memory of that class is minimal as i hate theory; but in essence it seems like the language needs to just force balance. I can't recall the symbol for at least or more

Comment: @SomeStudent: this is very roughly speaking a Dyck language, which is not regular. (But it is context free.)

Comment: No, thats not the answer. For example, 101 cant be generated using that grammar. But i will have a look at some of the ideas.